# How to escape and replace '\' in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

We'd like to replace `\` to `\\` in our master files, which can prevent upload on Redshift (once replaced `\\` can be uploaded without issue and it would be uploaded single `\`, same as original customer data).

I tried to replace `\` to `\\` as follows but received a regular expression error in PowerShell:

```
Param(
    [string]$TargetFileName
)

# replace words
$old='`\'
$new='`\`\'

# replace \ to \\ for Redshift upload
$file_contents=$(Get-Content "$TargetFileName") -replace $old,$new
$file_contents > $StrExpFile
```

Error Message:

```
+ $file_contents=$(Get-Content "$TargetFileName") -replace $old,$new
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (`\:String) []、RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression
```

Simply doing `-replace '\','\\'` didn't work either.

We'd like to save it as the same file name, but the file size can be big, so if you have any better ideas, also would be so much appreciated.

Comment: you can also use the built in regex escape method. this `[regex]::Escape()` will accept a string and add the needed escape chars. no need to parse it manually ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, many thanks for another brilliant idea. Thanks to you, I'm more intersted in PowerShell, actually it can provide many choices for us :)

Comment: you are quite welcome ... i'm glad to have been able to help! [*grin*]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-Replace` uses regular expressions, and in RegEx `\` is a special character (the escape character) so to escape a single slash you need to use another slash: `\\`. Note this is only true for `$old` (the text you want to match) the replacing text `$new` is not a regex, so here you still just need `\\`.

```
$old = '\\'
$new = '\\'
$file_contents = (Get-Content "$TargetFileName") -replace $old,$new
```

Alternatively, you could use the `.replace()` method which doesn't use regular expressions:

```
$old = '\'
$new = '\\'
$file_contents = (Get-Content "$TargetFileName").replace($old,$new)
```

Comment: Mark, thank you so much, both worked as we definetly expected!! And thank you so much for your alternative way, it's more simple :)  I really appreciate experts like you at Stackoverflow always help me.

Answer (score 0):

I use a command with parameter , which will replace `store:Schema="abcd"` to empty string, I escape `"` to `""` or `""""` as:

```
powershell -Command "$varStr='store:Schema=""abcd""""'; $filePath='%~dp0SomeFolder\SomeFile.txt'; (gc $filePath) -replace $varStr, '' | Out-File $filePath"
```

Comment: So sorry for my too late reply, but I really appreciated your useful advice. Thank you!!